# Calculate probability using tree diagram and bayes theorem

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability, graphical-model

We have the tree diagram as shown below,
[image]

I'm asked to find probability that a child who tests as right-handed will be left-handed?

I know we have to use Bayes Theorem and find ...

P(Actual Left handed | Tests as right-handed), however I'm not able to proceed further, Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please add the `self-study` tag and read its description.

Answer (score 3):

First, let us apply Bayes formula as usual, then we will see if we can identify that as operations on the probability tree:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\P(\text{L} \mid \text{test R}) =\frac{\P(\text{test R}\mid \text{L})\P(L)}{\P(\text{test R})}
$$
Comparing this with the probability tree below, we see it involve all the nodes except the two "Tests as left-handed",

[image]

so we can redraw the tree without those nodes:

[image]

Then let us put the numbers into the Bayes formula above:
$$
\P(\text{L} \mid \text{test R}) =\frac{(0.1)\cdot(0)}{(0.1)\cdot (0) + (0.9)\cdot (0.95)} = 0
$$
Then observe that in numerator we have the (sum of) path probabilities that passes through the node "Actually left-handed" (denoted `L` in the formulas here), while in the numerator we have the (sum of) all path probabilities that leads to one of the nodes "test as right-handed".

We can formulate that as a rule for applying Bayes theorem on a probability tree, for $\P(A \mid B)$, naming $A$ as 'cause' and $B$ as 'data':

1. Eliminate all the paths through the tree made impossible by the conditioning on data $B$.
2. Denominator is sum of all path-probabilities consistent with $B$
3. Numerator is sum of all path-probabilities consistent with cause $A$

Comment: Concept is now more clear, however we want to calculate probability that a child who test right will be a left handed. Also I understand there is a typo and writing numerator  twice.